# V8 JavaScript engine implementation languages

Tags: javascript, c++, google-chrome, implementation

Looking from the wiki articale on V8 Javascript engine it says that it is written in C++ and JavaScript itself but what does that exactly mean?I mean What is written in C++ and what is in Javascript? And how these 2 languages work with each other?

---

V8 JavaScript Engine

Developer(s)    Google

Stable release  4.1.0[1] / March 3, 2015; 5 days ago

Development status  Active

Written in  C++, JavaScript

Operating system    Cross-platform

Platform    IA-32, x86-64, ARM, MIPS

Type    JavaScript engine

License BSD
Website code.google.com/p/v8

Comment: Go and look, it's Open Source https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/master

Comment: @RichardCritten how I'm supposed to read it and understand it ?

Comment: If you can't read the source code, how do you expect to understand any answers given here?

Comment: Because it's two very different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

V8 is a C++ library that you can use to run JavaScript code. It can be used in any C++ application that wishes to execute JavaScript code. The most popular example is a web browser like Google Chrome, but its used in lots of different places.

From the V8 website:

**What is V8?**
V8 is Google's open source high-performance JavaScript engine, written in C++ and used in Google Chrome, the open source browser from Google. It implements ECMAScript as specified in ECMA-262, 3rd edition, and runs on Windows XP and Vista, Mac OS X 10.5+, and Linux systems that use IA-32, ARM or MIPS processors. V8 can run standalone, or can be embedded into any C++ application.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript files are here for runtime support ( arithmetics helpers, arrays, iterators...). I would think that C++ files and header are compiled to a native executable that supports a subset of JavaScript language. When the executable is started, his first action is to read the JS files, and so you have  the full JavaScript language available.